# What is the meaning of the blue icon at the right-top corner in Far Cry: New Dawn?

Tags: far-cry-new-dawn

What is the meaning of the blue icon at the right-top corner in *Far Cry: New Dawn*?

[image: screenshot]

Yellow icon → Skill points count
Green icon → Ethanol count
Blue icon → ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are ["Far Cry Credits"](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Cry_Credits_(Currency)), a "premium" currency that can be bought for real-world money, or found in each of the 10 Prepper Stashes (45 credits per stash).

It can be used as a substitute for certain crafting materials, for purchasing cosmetic items and acquiring higher tier weapons & vehicles.